# spring jpa connect failed to postgres server

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I create spring project to do the CRUD to the postgres database server but get some error.

**HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata**

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]

**Here is my application.properties**

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://3.1.84.18:5432/postgres

spring.datasource.username=postgres

spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

**my pom.xml**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGQcC.png)

Comment: thank, in file pg_hba.config we update the " host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5". I changed from ident to md5 authentication method, it works!

Comment: Please do **not** post (XML) code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml is correct

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

After you must create a postgre user with a password, and then create a postgre database

And on your application.properties, you can use the user created with his password

```
spring.datasource.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name
spring.datasource.username=user_name
spring.datasource.password=user_password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: my issues is, after trying to resolve "not connected to the database", I changed the pg_hba.conf with

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ident

we retry with host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5, and issues resolved.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

my issues is, after trying to resolve "not connected to the database", I changed the **pg_hba.conf** with host all all 0.0.0.0/0 ident we retry with host all all 0.0.0.0/0 **md5**,
and issue got resolved.

thank you